# Retrieving rate limit status with Twitter's REST API

Tags: php, api, object, twitter

I'm working with the REST API from Twitter, using abraham's twitteroauth lib. I'm trying to get the rate limit status of my api key to be able to show it directly on my admin panel, I'm using something like :

```
$rate = $connection->get('application/rate_limit_status');
print_r($rate->resources->statuses);
```

But I have no idea how to get for example only the '/statuses/home_timeline' status. I've tried several things like `$rate->resources->statuses->'/statuses/home_timeline'` or `$rate->resources->statuses['/statuses/home_timeline']` but nothing seems to work.

Can someone maybe get me on the right way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try $rate->resources->statuses->{'/statuses/home_timeline'}